# QXDM Application Not Launching

Tags: python, com, win32com

I am trying to automate QXDM Application in python.
Tried using win32com.client module.
Following is the code which I am trying, but it doesn't open QXDM application.

```
    from win32com.client import Dispatch
    qxdm_instance = Dispatch("QXDM.QXDMAutoApplication")
```

When I print qxdm_instance, it gives value:
COMObject QXDM.QXDMAutoApplication

But QXDM Application is not launched. I see splash screen of QXDM & it disappears immediately. When I go to TaskManager, I see QXDM.exe running there, but no GUI.

Any idea, why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of a lot of programs is that if they started "automated" than they are started invisible. Also they usually terminate when the last COM objects gets out of scope.

The MS-Office products behave the same. After an instance is created you must set a property `Visible` to true to show it.

But the details you get by the developer of `QXDM.QXDMAutoApplication`

**Update** as by the comment of Vinayak wagh

There is a window object. The visible attribute must be applied to this object.

```
window=qxdm_instance.GetAutomationWindow()
window.setVisible(True)
```

Comment: Tried setting qxdm_instance.Visible=1, but gives error: AttributeError: Property 'QXDM.QXDMAutoApplication.Visible' can not be set.

Comment: Than my answer isn't appropriate for this. Maybe the property is named different. Read the docs.

Comment: Check the other methods of this object, if there is a similar thing like Visible..., otherwise there is a hard way. You may change the flags how the application is launched by OLE automation in the registry.

Comment: Got solution. Need to get another object from COM object using window=qxdm_instance.GetAutomationWindow(). And then use setVisible(True) on that object. window.setVisible(True)

Comment: Ahhh. So my answer was the correct one... I update the answer to reflect your comment